# Why is my background color only applying to my padding?

Tags: html, css

For the life of me I cannot figure out why my background color for #mainContent is only applying to the padding. I really want it to fill the entire container but no matter what I add or remove, the background color won't budge. Removing the padding removes the background color entirely.

```css
* {
  background-color: lavenderblush;
  margin: 0;
}

body {
  font-family: 'Playfair Display', serif;
}

header {
  margin-top: 10%;
  text-align: center;
}

h1 {
  font-family: 'Sacramento', cursive;
  font-size: 400%;
  color: white;
  padding: 10px;
  background-color: rgba(198, 79, 119, 0.5);
}

h2 {
  font-size: 200%;
  padding: 20px;
  color: rgba(198, 79, 119, 0.5);
}

#mainContent {
  background-color: #FFF;
  padding: 20px;
  height: 100%;
  width: 50%;
  margin: auto;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 2em;
}

footer {
  font-weight: bold;
  padding: 10px;
  margin: auto;
  width: 50%;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="invite-style.css">
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Playfair+Display|Sacramento" rel="stylesheet">
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Invitation</title>
</head>

<body>
<header>
 <h1>Lloyd &amp; Diane's Wedding</h1>
</header>
<section id="mainContent">
 <h2>April 14, 1989 at <time datetime="15:00">3:00PM</time></h2>
    <dl>
     <dt>Hilton Seattle </dt>
        <dd>1301 6TH AVENUE</dd>
        <dd>SEATTLE, WASHINGTON, 98101</dd>
    </dl>
   <p>Join Lloyd &amp; Diane as they take a leap of faith into holy matrimony. Reception to follow ceremony.</p>
</section>
<footer>Kindly RSVP to Corey &amp; DC at <a href="tel:1-555-867-5309">1-555-867-5309</a> by April 1st</footer>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Its always better to apply the background-color of the page to the body and not all the elements in the html page. Here's a snippet of the working code:

```css
* {     
  margin: 0;
}

body {
background-color: lavenderblush;
  font-family: 'Playfair Display', serif;
}

header {
  margin-top: 10%;
  text-align: center;
}

h1 {
  font-family: 'Sacramento', cursive;
  font-size: 400%;
  color: white;
  padding: 10px;
  background-color: rgba(198, 79, 119, 0.5);
}

h2 {
  font-size: 200%;
  padding: 20px;
  color: rgba(198, 79, 119, 0.5);
}

#mainContent {
  background-color: #FFF;
  padding: 20px;
  height: 100%;
  width: 50%;
  margin: auto;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 2em;
}

footer {
  font-weight: bold;
  padding: 10px;
  margin: auto;
  width: 50%;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="invite-style.css">
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Playfair+Display|Sacramento" rel="stylesheet">
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Invitation</title>
</head>

<body>
<header>
 <h1>Lloyd &amp; Diane's Wedding</h1>
</header>
<section id="mainContent">
 <h2>April 14, 1989 at <time datetime="15:00">3:00PM</time></h2>
    <dl>
     <dt>Hilton Seattle </dt>
        <dd>1301 6TH AVENUE</dd>
        <dd>SEATTLE, WASHINGTON, 98101</dd>
    </dl>
   <p>Join Lloyd &amp; Diane as they take a leap of faith into holy matrimony. Reception to follow ceremony.</p>
</section>
<footer>Kindly RSVP to Corey &amp; DC at <a href="tel:1-555-867-5309">1-555-867-5309</a> by April 1st</footer>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your rule `background-color: lavenderblush;` is applying to the `h2` inside of `#mainContent`, making the inner element have the background color. In the future, right click on an element in Chrome and choose "inspect element" to help debug things like this.

Answer (score 0):

* {

background-color: lavenderblush;

  margin: 0;

}

Issue coming due to this code block. This one over ride  background-color of every block